# App not compatible with Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, manifest, compatibility, galaxy-tab

I recently released an update to an app.  Since the update I have received several emails asking why it's not compatible with the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 anymore.

The only addition to the manifest is the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and the following added to the application tag in the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

In the developer console it says the Galaxy Tab 10.1 is supported, so why is there an issue with it not being compatible?

Comment: what does "not compatible" mean?  Is there an issue with the application running properly, or is the google play store saying that it is not compatible.  Are you getting this error on attempted install?  Was it working before the update?  Thanks

Comment: From what I understand from the emails I have received.  Before the update, there were no issues. After the update, the Google Play store is saying not compatible.  I am waiting for more information on that from the users.

Comment: I have the same issue.. Not compatible is a warning the device is given when they try to download the app from Google Play. For some devices my app doesn't even show in Google Play, as they can detect some sort of permission or minSDK issue that they aren't compatible with. I have added that all options are optional and I have added all of the suggestions below, but still it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

Try including support for android:xlargeScreens by inserting this into your manifest

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

More info can be found in [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the lines you added, but they could be functions with a minimum API that is too high for the Galaxy Tab 10.1.

Comment: Thank you, but the minimum API is set to 4, so android 1.6 and above.  There shouldn't be any issues with minimum api

Comment: @mem You've misunderstood me. I'm not talking about the app's minimum API, just the minimum API required for the feature you added. The number is different from feature to feature.

Comment: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE was added in API level 4.  So that should not be an issue with Galaxy Tab.   Not sure about the android:style to set it to full screen though, will need to look into that.